# How to jump between block of code in excel macro?

Tags: vba, excel

```
LongitudeValue:
         'Longitude Value
          C = C + 1
          SrcWkb.Worksheets("sheet1").Range("N8:P8").Copy
            DstWks1.Cells(R, C).Select
             Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False

FarEndSiteName:
           'Farend SIte Name
            C = C + 1
           SrcWkb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A").Copy
            DstWks1.Cells(R, C).Select
             Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Is it possible to jump between between two block of code when error occours in `LongitudeValue` block of code so that code will resume from `FarEndSiteName`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `On Error Goto <Label>`

Typical use is

```
Sub MySub()
    Dim ...
    On Error Goto EH
    ' code...

CleanUp:
    On Error Resume Next
    ' Tidy up code...

Exit Sub
EH:
    If Err.Number = <some particular error> Then
        '  error handling code

        Resume  ' or Resume Next
    End If

    GoTo CleanUp

End Sub
```